# Interpreting GAM Coefficients

Tags: r, regression-coefficients, generalized-additive-model

I could use some advice interpreting GAM (Generalized Additive Model) coefficients.

I get the following results when I call `coef` on my model:

```
(Intercept)     s(TM).1     s(TM).2     s(TM).3
   817.9501    383.7981   2358.5184   -545.4162
```

Does that mean:

```
y = 817.9501 + 383.7981*TM + 2358.5184*TM^2 - 545.4162*TM^3
```

Comment: What was the model formula you used in R for your model?

Comment: gam1 <- gam(Rev ~ s(TM), family = gaussian, data = data1)

Answer (score 11):

Not at all. For one thing, GAM's need a [link function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function), and also smoothers, the $g$ and the $f$'s, respectively, in the general definition:

$$\mathbb{E}(y)=g^{-1}\left(\alpha+f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2) + \dots + f_n(x_n) \right)$$

For this reason you cannot follow the exact same usual marginal contribution interpretation done with simple linear regression; the link function and the smoothing terms get in the way.

One usual approach for GAM's is plotting the partial effects and inspect the relationships between $y$ and $x$'s visually. [This article](http://environmentalcomputing.net/intro-to-gams/) has a really nice intro to GAM's with a short discussion on interpretation in the end.

Answer (score 2):

From your R syntax, it seems like you are fitting a regression model which postulates that the predictor variable TM has a potentially nonlinear effect on the response (or outcome) variable Rev. (If you had reasons to believe the effect is linear, you would use the lm() function instead of the gam() function.)

I am presuming the reason you are trying to fit a gam model is because you plotted Rev against TM and noticed some kind of nonlinearity in that plot. (Rev should be a continuous variable.)

When the gam() function is invoked for your data, it will essentially try to fit the following model to the data:

```
Rev = intercept + f(TM) + error
```

where f() is an unknown potentially linear function whose shape must be identified from the data and error is a random error term assumed to come from a normal distribution with mean 0 and unknown standard deviation sigma.

To estimate the function f(), gam will approximate f() by a linear combination of known basis functions and estimate the unknown weights these functions will receive in that combination.

What you see in your output is that gam identified that three such basis functions were sufficient to recover the underlying shape of f(): s(TM).1, s(TM).2 and s(TM).3.  (All of these are known functions which depend on TM.)

R estimated the weights one should give to each of these functions in the linear combination that will approximate f(). So the function f() can be estimated as follows:

```
Estimated value of f(TM) ~ 383.7981*s(TM).1 + 2358.5184*s(TM).2 - 545.4162*s(TM).3
```

This means that the expected/average value of Rev can be estimated as:

```
Expected Rev = 817.9501 + 383.7981*s(TM).1 + 2358.5184*s(TM).2 - 545.4162*s(TM).3
```

In this context, you wouldn't want to interpret the effects of s(TM).1, s(TM).2 and s(TM).3 on the expected value of Rev. Rather, you would simply want to see how these three basis functions combine together via the estimated weights to produce a possibly nonlinear function which represents the nonlinear effect of TM on Rev. That is why it is important to simply plot 383.7981*s(TM).1 + 2358.5184*s(TM).2 - 545.4162*s(TM).3 against TM and interpret qualitatively the shape of that plot. For example, does the plot show that the expected value of Rev increases up to a point and then levels off?

This link will give you more detailed explanations on gam models and what they do under their hood: http://environmentalcomputing.net/intro-to-gams/. It will also give you clues on how to plot the possibly nonlinear effect f() you are trying to estimate.

Comment: In my application, I am hoping to use the GAM to make predictions.

Comment: In my application, I am hoping to use the GAM to make predictions. The folks who will consume these predictions will not have access to R.  Instead, they will be using CPQ - or configure, price, quote - software.  I need to get the model results somehow out of R and into this software.  It would be easy to do this with an LM model where I can see the complete functions.

Is there some way to see the actual basis functions.  For example, what exactly is s(TM).1?

Comment: @D.Kent: Thank you for your clarifications. The link I mentioned at the end of my answer explains in detail how you can extract the actual basis functions. Did you have a look at it? If anything in there is unclear, perhaps you can come back to this forum with specific questions about what you don't understand.  See the section Basis Functions of that link.

Comment: I can see from the article how the basis functions are plotted.  What I don't see is the code that produces the actual equation for the basis function.  For example is s(x).2 simply "x^2"?

Comment: Hmmm .  .  . from the post below, I am wondering if the answer to my question below is the actual basis equations cannot be produced from R.  Which would really be unfortunate.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851861/mgcv-how-to-get-spline-equations

Comment: If you care about prediction, all that would matter is how the fitted nonlinear effects included in the model add up together to produce the predicted value of the response.

Comment: Even if you cared about the explicit components of a fitted nonlinear effect f(x) look like, you can certainly export the s(x).1, s(x).2, etc. and plot those - they are not simple polynomials like x, x^2; their expression is derived iteratively rather than using explicit formulas and depends on the underlying set of basis functions used to fit the model (e.g., cubic splines will lead to different expressions for s(x).1 and s(x).2 compared to thin plate splines).

Comment: I guess if you have a single predictor, you can use polynomial regression, though you'd need to work with a basis of orthogonal polynomials since x, x^2, etc. could lead to collinearity.  The mathematical formulas involved in the definition of a basis of spline functions can get complicated quickly which is why iteration comes in handy. In any event, in a predictive context, you really shouldn't need explicit formulas for the fitted effects - in my view, that is overkill. Just show plots of the fitted effects - that should be sufficient to indicate what is going on.

Comment: In general, gam models lend themselves to a qualitative interpretation of fitted nonlinear effects (assuming you were interested in describing these effects in the first place) - something like: the effect increases sharply and then stabilizes, etc. The statistical methodology behind gam models is quite complex - one could say that it is unfortunate that is the case (and R obviously inherits this complexity), but that would be pointless in my opinion. The methodology is what it is and we either can work with its constraints or switch to simpler methodology if possible.

Comment: If a gam model indicates that an effect is linear, quadratic or cubic, then we can re-fit the model using (orthogonal) polynomial terms, as that would make the effect easier to interpret. Or if the model indicates that the effect can be described by a broken line, then we can re-fit the model so we can report linear effects captured by the broken line. But other than that, if more complicated effect forms emerge, the best we can do is to retain the gam model and describe the effect qualitatively. Again, description of a nonlinear effect Is not necessary in a predictive context.

Comment: Since the nonlinear effect is a weighted sum of basis functions, description of those basis functions is also not necessary in a predictive context. Of course, it helps to know what the nonlinear effect looks like, but that information should be optional. Even if you were able to state an explicit equation that drives the shape of the nonlinear effect, not too many people would be able to interpret it unless you showed a plot of the estimated nonlinear effect - which you can do in R.